# Peculiar behavior with Python metaclasses

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm working on a coding puzzle shown [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54bebed0d5b56c5b2600027f/train/python).  My solution is shown and I've included the test cases which pass on my local computer but fail when submitted.  It appears as though none of the instrumentation for the attribute accesses occur, but only when submitted online.  Can someone help me?

```
import functools
import codewars_test as test


class Debugger(object):
    attribute_accesses = []
    method_calls = []


class AttributeAccessDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, attr_name):
        self.attr_name = attr_name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        value = instance.__dict__[self.attr_name]
        print(f"Attribute '{self.attr_name}' accessed with value: {value}")
        Debugger.attribute_accesses.append(
            {'action': 'get',
             'class': instance.__class__,
             'attribute': self.attr_name,
             'value': value
             }
        )
        return value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print(f"Attribute '{self.attr_name}' set with value: {value}")
        Debugger.attribute_accesses.append(
            {'action': 'set',
             'class': instance.__class__,
             'attribute': self.attr_name,
             'value': value
             }
        )
        instance.__dict__[self.attr_name] = value


class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for key, value in attrs.items():
            if callable(value):
                attrs[key] = cls.wrap_method(value)
            elif not key.startswith("__"):
                attrs[key] = AttributeAccessDescriptor(key)
        print(f"__new__: cls = {cls}, name = {name}, bases = {bases}, attrs = {attrs}")
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    @staticmethod
    def wrap_method(method):
        @functools.wraps(method)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f'method = {method}')
            if method.__name__ != '__init__':
                Debugger.attribute_accesses.append(
                    {'action': 'get',
                     'class': args[0].__class__,
                     'attribute': method.__name__,
                     }
                )
            Debugger.method_calls.append(
                {'class': args[0].__class__.__name__, 'method': method.__name__, 'args': args, 'kwargs': kwargs})
            return method(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped


class Foo(object, metaclass=Meta):
    x = 0

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def bar(self, v):
        return self.x, v


a = Foo(1)
a.bar(2)

print(Debugger.method_calls)
print(Debugger.attribute_accesses)

calls = Debugger.method_calls

test.assert_equals(len(calls), 2)

test.describe("Test collected method calls")

test.it("Call to init should be collected")
test.assert_equals(calls[0]['args'], (a, 1))

test.it("Call to bar should be collected")
test.assert_equals(calls[1]['args'], (a, 2))

test.describe("Test collected attribute accesses")
accesses = Debugger.attribute_accesses

test.assert_equals(len(accesses), 3)

test.it("Attribute set in init should be collected")
test.assert_equals(accesses[0]['action'], 'set')
test.assert_equals(accesses[0]['attribute'], 'x')
test.assert_equals(accesses[0]['value'], 1)

test.it("Method get should be collected too")
test.assert_equals(accesses[1]['action'], 'get')
test.assert_equals(accesses[1]['attribute'], 'bar')

test.it("Attribute get should be collected")
test.assert_equals(accesses[2]['action'], 'get')
test.assert_equals(accesses[2]['attribute'], 'x')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the tests presented are the only things that will be tested for the full exercise?

Your instrumentation is ok, but it does not take in account corner cases that makes this kind of code hard to do for production - for example,you write `x=0` as a class attribute, so your metaclass catches it! What if `x` is only set in `__init__` and never shows up on the class body or as a class attribute? This is most likely what is going wrong there.

But also, in case of class inheritance, you method calls will be counted twice - once for the child and another for the base class.

And, going deeper into corner cases: you are hard-coded guarding the access to `__init__` from being counted as an attribute access, but you are not doing so against any of the other  "dunder" methods that can be called without going through attribute-retrieval - any of `__repr__`, `__add__`, and so on should not be counted as well.

I'd guess the first issue and this later one are the point your example is failing - this last one is easier to fix, just test if the method-name begins and ends with `__` instead of just comparing it to `__init__`.

If the problem is the one of double-counting method calls on inheritance, it is harder to fix. You have to guess what their expected behavior is - in case their tests involve classes that use inheritance and call methods on the superclasses. Your approach counts both calls. Also, if it does count both calls, what should the logged class be? The child class to which the instance belongs, or the class where each method is actually defined?

These are all ambiguities in the enunciate you will have to face by trial and error.

Moreover, like I said - real world for meta-programming can be tough: they don't mention it, but what if some of their test-classes use themselves descriptors on attributes? What of if any class use `__slots__`? (there is no `__dict__` on the class)

I'd approach this by instrumenting `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__`, instead of creating a descriptor for each attribute. This would solve both the problem of attributes created as instance attributes alone, and also can handle descriptors and `__slots__`. I'd say this is what the proponent of the exercise had in mind. If it still does not pass, them tackle the question of double-logging when inheritance is involved. Wrapping the methods for logging the calls as you are doing sounds good for a start anyway.